# pymodbus Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress)

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', baudrate=9600, parity='E', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=1)
client.connect()

rr = client.read_holding_registers(40000, 7, unit=0x01)
print rr
client.close()
```

But I get only this:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Response[131]
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:adding transaction 0
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:getting transaction 1
Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress)
```

On the other hand this C code (using libmodbus) is working:

```
modbus_t *mb;
int16_t hregs[9];
mb = modbus_new_rtu('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, 'E', 8, 1);
modbus_set_slave(mb, 1);
modbus_read_registers(mb, 0x40000, 7, hregs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your libmodbus code is working? You're reading address 0x40000 (262144), no Modbus slave will accept this address.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that C code is working.

Comment: Did you try with `0x40000` or `0x400` (as a default in many cases)? `0x40000` (hexadecimal) have different with `40000` (decimal)

Comment: The other odd thing was that libmodbus was 'working'. 0x40000 has too many zeros -- it's not a valid modbus address

Answer (score 2):

> Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress) means:

A value contained in the query data field is not an allowable value for the slave.  This indicates a fault in the structure of remainder of a complex request, such as that the implied length is incorrect. It specifically does NOT mean that a data item submitted for storage in a register has a value outside the expectation of the application program, since the MODBUS protocol is unaware of the significance of any particular value of any particular register.

> http://www.simplymodbus.ca/exceptions.htm

---

[UPDATE]:

Did you try with `0x40000` or `0x400` (as a default in many cases)? `0x40000` (hexadecimal) have different with `40000` (decimal)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to read the first seven holding registers. In that case, the address to be given to the `read_holding_registers` function is **0**. The function implicitly adds the offset of 40000 for holding registers.

So, try changing your read code to this

```
rr = client.read_holding_registers(0, 7, unit=0x01)
```